# "There is nothing to install or update" while creating new project on Android Studio

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I update to latest version **0.85 beta** on Android Studio,and when I create a new project at  last step that it prompts me "*There is nothing to install or update*" and progessbar always on loading.

ps:I use the **Android SDK** which path from **ADT**
[image: what it looks like]

Comment: I have same problem if you have found any solution let me know thanks. I have changed the API level but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I started anew project and chose a different Minimum API this time, and the problem was solved.
you can always change the minimum API ;)
I was choosing Minimum  API 9 before, then I Chose API 14 (Android 4.0)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have changed API level and i also used proxy for downloading new android SDK and updating it to latest version I have changed many thing but still while creating a project this problem happens again have you got any other idea?

Comment: have you set proxy for SDK Manager ?

Comment: @saeed can create a new project using a different API ?
are you using it in Iran ?

Comment: Keshazvarzian Yes I am in Iran and also I have used a proxy as well, By the way I have tried other API platforms as well.

Comment: Try downloading the whole SDK from this link:

http://p30download.com/fa/entry/39533/

Comment: @saeed this way you have all sdk versions needed downloaded

Comment: I had solved this problem in some other computers, Yes whole the SDK is needed and AS tries to download previous platforms.... Any way whole the SDK is needed , there are some problems with Gradle These days I'm busy and there is not much time to spend on AS, so I will touch it some other time thanks for respond.

Comment: your welcome, I didn't have that much problem using AS, and since I was starting a new project, I decided to use AS for its future ;-)

Comment: Well done , hope to meet each other for serious projects and business on AS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by:

1. Downloading and installing the requested build tools or platform from the SDK manager.
2. After installation (you can find the downloaded zip files in a temp folder placed in the android-sdk folder in program files - C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp), go to the build tools folder, find the dx.bat file and execute it.